# JSON Data Models and web services

Tags: json, deserialization

We are using web services (web api) to return data structures using JSON.  For example

```
{ "name": "Bob", "age": "20" }
```

The real structures are more complicated.  We would like to have the consuming clients de-serialize the structures and we were looking for some best practices.  The two ideas we have are:

1. Create a project that has the objects and have each client import that project.
2. Copy and paste the objects into each client app.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood you question is such way as that you plan to create multiple web service clients using the same programming language.

In this case you are best of in creating a common library with the objects used to deserialize the JSON. The reason for this is quite simple: As with most APIs you will have changes in your web services - if you then modify your common library, you will get compilation errors, which will show you where your clients will no longer fit the JSON.

This will prove valuable for maintenance.